# Cartopy plotting extra points at poles when passed one at a time

Tags: python, cartopy

When plotting an orthographic projection with some points on the other side of the globe, how come the first approach plots as expected, but the second takes all the points that would be on the other side of the globe and plots them at the pole of the projection? Is there a solution beyond filtering out the points that are out of sight, and if not what is the best way to do that for a pole at an arbitrary lon/lat (as opposed to the north pole, which is relatively trivial)?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

projection = ccrs.Orthographic(0, 90)
transform = ccrs.Geodetic()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = projection)

ax.coastlines()
ax.set_global()
ax.gridlines()

npoints = 100
np.random.seed(71077345)
lon = np.random.sample(npoints) * 360
lat = np.random.sample(npoints) * 180 - 90
plt.plot(lon,
         lat,
         'ro',
         alpha = 0.3,
         transform = transform)

for i in range(npoints):
    plt.plot(lon[i],
             lat[i],
             'b.',
             alpha = 0.3,
             transform = transform)
```

[image: example with extra points at the pole]

Comment: One potential work-around to the problem for the arbitrary pole is to treat the pole as vector (```x=cos(lat)cos(lon);y=cos(lat)sin(lon);z=sin(lat)```) and then do the same thing for each point to plot. If the dot product of the two points is >= 0, then it is in the hemisphere; otherwise it is not. Still, I'm wondering if there is a way to do it within the package.

Comment: I suspect that it is a bug. The points below equator (lat<0) should not be plotted in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in v0.19 and beyond by [#1710](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/pull/1710).

Answer (score 0):

(Partial answer to the question)

To filter the points on the upper hemisphere, use this code

```
for i in range(npoints):
    if lat[i]>=0:
        # this plots points above/on equator
        ccode = 'b^'
        ax.plot( lon[i], lat[i],
            ccode,
            alpha = .3,
            transform = ccrs.PlateCarree()
        )
    else:
        # this skips points below equator
        pass
```

Comment: That will work when the pole of the projection is the north pole, but not when the pole is , e.g. 25 N 135 E. That is why I suggested in my comment on the initial question to use a dot product test.